COMO REMOVER PROMT DO CMD AO ABRIR SELENIUM
to fazendo um sistema no python usando selenium que abre o wpp e estou usando pra converter em .exe no pyinstaller
exemplo: pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile zap_app.pyw
Porém, o cmd/promt toda vez abre por causa do selenium, quero saber como faço pra ele não abrir.
def iniciar_navegador():
    opcoes = EdgeOptions()
    opcoes.use_chromium = True
    opcoes.add_argument("--inprivate")
    opcoes.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    opcoes.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    opcoes.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    opcoes.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    opcoes.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    opcoes.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    opcoes.add_argument("--log-level=OFF")  # Desativa completamente os logs
    opcoes.add_argument("--disable-logging")  # Desativa o logging

    caminho_edgedriver = 'msedgedriver'

    try:
        # Tentativa de iniciar o navegador
        navegador = Edge(executable_path=caminho_edgedriver, options=opcoes)
        navegador.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
    except WebDriverException:
        # Se der erro, baixa a versão mais recente do msedgedriver e tenta novamente
        print(Fore.RED + "Erro no msedgedriver." + Fore.GREEN + "Baixando a versão mais recente...")
        baixar_msedgedriver()
        navegador = Edge(executable_path=caminho_edgedriver, options=opcoes)
        navegador.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
    return navegador

ele abrir desse jeito
promt do cmd selenium

Cara já passei por isso e tenho um aplicativo que usa o Selenium.
 pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile --windowed zap_app.py

Depois que comecei a usar dessa maneira meu terminal não apareceu mais.
Fazendo outras pesquisas encontrei outro link que contém bastantes respostas relacionadas.
Caso essa alternativa não dê certo, vale a pena tentar.

tentei aqui, mas não deu man. To é puto já com esse ngc. Não acho solução nunca kkk
Faz uns meses q já tentei, mas desitir, ai to procurando de novo uma solução. Fiz até um codigo pequeno pra ver se vai, mas nada
from selenium import webdriver
# Configuração do WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
# Abre o WhatsApp Web
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
